# Blend modes and effects such as glow in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, blending

I am new to this forum, started working as an animator: Don't know anything about cocos, so my question is, can we make composition in cocos 2d, like how we change blend modes and all in Photoshop ? Also is it possible to generate effects such as glow in cocos 2d ? 
Please sort out my doubts guys. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can..
e.g:

```
sprite.blendMode = [CCBlendMode blendModeWithOptions: @{
                       CCBlendFuncSrcColor: @(GL_SRC_ALPHA),
                       CCBlendFuncDstColor: @(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA),
                       }];
```

for effects check CCEffect class, you can add blur, brightness, contrast and many more